# using rsync to measure difference between filesystems?

Tags: debian, filesystems, rsync, virtual-machine, nixos

I'm running some expiriments to test filesystem differences, for example upgrading an older nixOS version and newer one to the same flake/configuration, as well as the same with debian and ansible. I'm trying to measure which ones are the most similar, and have heard that rsync is a good tool for measuring this, yet i cant seem to find any good resources on using it for this purpose. I need to measure filesystem difference in terms of size, different content (e.g different bytes on the same file between filesystems), missing/existing files etc. obviously, i would not like to include any sort of timestamps. What does one typically use to measure this kind of thing, and if rsync, how? i plan to mount two qcow2 images with nbd if thats relevant.

Comment: `diff -qr /path1 /path2`?

Comment: @aviro but i need to measure things such as files existing on both systems but different, as well as sizes. not just file existance

Comment: @ebrowningizer that's already what the suggested command does

Comment: First of all, you said you wanted to also compare the content, so the size doesn't matter. If the content is different, it doesn't matter if the size is different as well. And have you tried running the `diff` command I showed you? It will tell you which files exist only in one path and not in the other, and also which files exist on both paths but are different. The only thing it won't show is files that both exist in both directories and have the same content.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of suggestions.

Scenario

```
mkdir -p a/c b/c
date | tee a/1 a/2 > a/c/3
who | tee b/2 > b/c/4
cp a/1 b/1

diff -qr a b

  Files a/2 and b/2 differ
  Only in a/c: 3
  Only in b/c: 4

rsync -nr -iv --delete --size-only --checksum a/ b | grep '^[<*>]'

  >fcsT...... 2      # "2" was in both but different
  *deleting   c/4    # "c/4" was in b but not in a
  >f+++++++++ c/3    # "c/3" was in a but not in b
```

These two commands will give you a report for files that are different as well as those missing from `a` or from `b`. (Neither is reliably machine-parseable, but I think `rsync` might have the edge. I've annotated the output from `rsync` since it's not necessarily obvious what each line indicates.)

In general I'd suggest `diff` for your situation, but you asked about `rsync` so I've included it here too.

Comment: Sorry for nitpicking again, but you don't need the `-v` (verbose) flag.  Without it you won't need the `grep`, the `-v` adds all the lines that you filter by the `grep`. :)

Comment: Also, you don't need `--size-only`. It has no effect in this case. This flag modifies the "quick check" algorithm to remove time based check. The `--checksum` flag overrides it, as it uses the checksum comparison **instead** of the "quick check" algorithm. So the checksum will be generated even when the size is different.